# How could i hide the window which one notice to install certificate(DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot)?

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, fiddlercore

I developed an wpf application based on fiddlerCore,witchhelp me capture https resources.then i found a question.It's also alert a window that notice to install certificate(DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot).i want hide this window.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu7Jn.png)

install certificate method just as below:

```
 public static bool InstallCertificate()
    {
        if (!CertMaker.rootCertExists())
        {
            if (!CertMaker.createRootCert())
                return false;

            if (!CertMaker.trustRootCert())
                return false;
            Cert = FiddlerApplication.Prefs.GetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.cert", null);
            Key = FiddlerApplication.Prefs.GetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.key", null);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunatly,i found a soulution to resolve this problem.
add codes as below to public void DoFiddler() in myfiddler.cs:

```
    CONFIG.bCaptureCONNECT = true;
    CONFIG.IgnoreServerCertErrors = false;
    if (!CertMaker.rootCertExists())
    {
        if (!CertMaker.createRootCert())
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to create cert for FiddlerCore.");
        }
        X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        try
        {
            certStore.Add(CertMaker.GetRootCertificate());
        }
        finally
        {
            certStore.Close();
        }
    }
```

just install certification and store it.

like this , you will not found "DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot" window!